# Idiom that means "to want to be sure"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms

Example sentence:

> I had all the evidence. Still, I __. So I decided to interrogate the suspect one more time.

Comment: I would use "wanted to be sure" in that gap. **Why** is that not acceptable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unclear what you're after. It's clear that you're looking for an idiom or phrase that means "to want to be sure", but since "wanted to be sure" appears to fit your sample sentence very well, it's not clear what's wrong with that phrase itself, or what criteria you would use to evaluate suggested idioms or phrases. Please [edit] your question to explain what you're after in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it can can be used more generically, a phrase which works especially for the example context is: ***wanted to make it watertight***

> I had all the evidence. Still, I ***wanted to make it (more) watertight***. So I decided to interrogate the
>   suspect one more time.

ODO:

> **[watertight](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/watertight)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **2** (of an argument or account) unable to be disputed or questioned.
>
> ‘They are having to ensure that their evidence is more watertight than
>   that which would be expected in a court of law.’

Comment: Just for the record you could equally use: *I wanted to make it* ***airtight***. Basically the same thing.